# Google Apps Script: Generating a PDF from a Document based on a Sheets row is not recognising the setValue updates from the same function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that;

1. Updates a row in a google sheet using setValue.
2. Generates a document based on the sheets row.

The generated document doesn't get the new value, I can show an alert of what the new value is and it updates the sheet fine.

I am finding this problem in many places, I have had a hard time finding anything about it

Answer (score 0):

figured it out as I was writing the question so may as well answer it;

The function assigned all the cell values to an array prior to the updates (setValue), the array needs to be updated as well as the sheets.